# How would I design this database?

Tags: database, performance, entity-framework, database-design

Every day I want to track how many "clicks"(int) a certain object in my database gets.

Now an int in the object called clicks obviously wouldn't help since I couldn't track the date of the clicks.

What way would be the smartest to store the daily clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the `VisitedDate` column in your tracking table.

```
RecordID INT Identity
ItemID INT
VisitedDate DateTime
IPAddress varchar(30)
```

Once you have the records, you can query and get the results for visits on a specific day/ month etc...

Comment: I see.
So I should create a new row for each visitor in the VisitedDate?
I don't know much about performance but say I get thousands of visitors of several hundreds of objects every day. Wouldn't that be very heavy performance-wise?

Comment: Doing this approach will give you an idea about each single visit.(What is the IP (what location visitor is from ) etc..) You need to avoid adding duplicate records for the day.

Comment: You may skip the RecordID column and then you can clear data from this table after a specific period of time (an year ?) on regular intervals to keep it not BIG

Answer (score 1):

Create a table as Shyju suggests (ip address is optional), and yes it will grow fast but if it becomes a problem you can rollup the data to a weekly (or monthly, or yearly) rollup table where it stores the total for that item, for that time period.

Best to always initially store the data at this lowest-level and roll up/archive to summary tables as needed down the road, because if you store the data initially at the roll up level you have lost that detail forever - tracking at the detail level keeps all your options open.

There are workarounds for performance if you need them, there are no workarounds to recreate data you never stored.

Comment: Alright I see :)
I've awarded Shyju as the best answer since he suggested it first but I appreciate your answer as well!

Answer (score 0):

**I insert or update on the go, on the clicks table.**

```
Clicks

(Product_id | Vendor_id | User_id)[unique] | Clicks | Created_at
```

Insert if the (Product_id | Vendor_id | User_id) combintaion does not exist. Update (+1 clicks), if that combination already exists.

I wouldn't worry about the performance right now, during the early stage.

If you still worry about it,

```
Use a javascript request and write the (Product_id | Vendor_id | User_id)[unique] | Clicks | Created_at into a textfile, onclick.
```

In the EOD, load the information in the file into clicks table.